# MPMoviePlayerController retainCount goes from 1 to 3 to 2. Then hangs my app

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, mpmovieplayercontroller

Inside the simulator, I load up my movie using the method described here:
https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#VIDEO-INITIATE_VIDEO_PLAYBACK_IN_MY_CODE

I'm doing an NSLog to show the retainCount before/after the play call, as well as before/after the release call in the notification. The count goes:
1 [before play]
3 [after play]
3 [before release]
2 [after release]

and at that point, the simulator is hung.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this method of using a different URL for each time your want to play a movie incompatible with the simulator?

Comment: Is there any chance you could post your code in which you are observing this behavior?